# Minimum column widths of NavigationSplitView

Tags: swiftui

I would like to dynamically set the minimum column widths of the NavigationSplitView according to the width of toolbar above each column. Please see the attached screenshot.

I don't know how to implement such a restriction.
The content view is:

```
struct ContentView: View {

  var body: some View {
    NavigationSplitView {
      CustomersView()
    } content: {
      CertsView()
    } detail: {
      DetailsView()
    }
    .background(Color.white)
    .controlSize(.large)
  }
}
```

and the CertsView is:

```
  @State var filterOptions: Options = Options(
    options: [
      Option(name: "All"),
      Option(name: "Running"),
      Option(name: "Valid")
    ],
    selection: "All"
  )

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text(filterOptions.selection)
        .toolbar {
          RadioToolbarView(options: $filterOptions)
        }
    }
  }
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZLN4.jpg)

Comment: I’m not sure if what you can is achievable but can I suggest that you use a different control? I think a segmented control or a dropdown would be more compact and look better than a horizontal radio group.

Comment: Since I am new to macOS UI, what could be a segmented control?

Comment: A segmented control would be a `Picker` with this style `.pickerStyle(.segmented)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using
`.navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 100, ideal: 200, max: 300)`

Comment: This is a solution, indeed, but I am wondering if these fixed values could be variables depending on width of the toolbar view, since the last one can be wider or narrower depending on the application state. Actually what I am trying to do is the layout of the standard Notes application of macOS